# Como preencher "espaços de sobra"

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um site, e nele está tendo um problema de uma div com 100% de largura e altura, posição absolute. O problema é que está div não está preenchendo por completo o espaço dela.
Ao fazer uns testes usando o depurador do Browser mesmo, verifiquei que se caso eu removesse a propriedade "Display: Table" da div pai resolveria o problema e resolveu, o problema é que o texto dentro da div filha tem que estar alinhado verticalmente no meio. Mas como resolver isso sem remover a propriedade?

**Screenshots:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A última imagem está com cores mais destacada(sAquele pequeno espaço em vermelho é o espaço de sobra que eu falei).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="destaque-galeria">
    <div>
        <img src="admin/upload_photo/imagens/thumbnail@2x/f257249f569ad165c66f2a76a3bb183e.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="admin/upload_photo/imagens/thumbnail@2x/6425a30e41cbb154a40cfa89a4a60191.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="Javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-destaque" onclick="getDestaque(32, 58)">
            <img src="admin/upload_photo/imagens/thumbnail@2x/844beefee8b3efb3f42db04c9eb1a2ce.jpeg">
            <div class="galeria-vejaMais">
                <span>+ 7</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.destaque-galeria {margin-top: 10px;}
.destaque-galeria>div{
    width: calc(33.33% - 5px);
    margin: 0 2.5px;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
}
.destaque-galeria>div:first-of-type{
    width: calc(33.33% - 5px);
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.destaque-galeria>div:last-of-type{
    width: calc(33.33% - 5px);
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
.destaque-galeria>div>a>.galeria-vejaMais {
    background-color: rgba(209, 154, 97, 0.6);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.galeria-vejaMais span{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara a forma como vc montou o layout poderia ser melhor. A forma que eu vou te sugerir vc não vai precisar mexer na estrutura do HTML e vai substituir o `display:table` por `display:flex`, e vai usar as propriedades do `flex` para fazer o alinhamento vertical e horizontal.

```css
.destaque-galeria {margin-top: 10px;}
.destaque-galeria>div{
    width: calc(33.33% - 5px);
    margin: 0 2.5px;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
}
.destaque-galeria>div:first-of-type{
    width: calc(33.33% - 5px);
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.destaque-galeria>div:last-of-type{
    width: calc(33.33% - 5px);
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
.destaque-galeria>div>a>.galeria-vejaMais {
    background-color: rgba(255, 130, 0, 0.6);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    /* alinha na horizontal no centro */
    justify-content: center;
    /* alinha na vertical no centro */
    align-items: center;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.galeria-vejaMais span{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="destaque-galeria">
    <div>
        <img src="admin/upload_photo/imagens/thumbnail@2x/f257249f569ad165c66f2a76a3bb183e.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="admin/upload_photo/imagens/thumbnail@2x/6425a30e41cbb154a40cfa89a4a60191.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="Javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-destaque" onclick="getDestaque(32, 58)">
            <img src="admin/upload_photo/imagens/thumbnail@2x/844beefee8b3efb3f42db04c9eb1a2ce.jpeg">
            <div class="galeria-vejaMais">
                <span>+ 7</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado, e um abraço!